# Why does Powershell file concatenation convert UTF8 to UTF16?

Tags: powershell, utf-8, utf-16, data-conversion

I am running the following Powershell script to concatenate a series of output files into a single CSV file. `whidataXX.htm` (where `xx` is a two digit sequential number) and the number of files created varies from run to run.

```
$metadataPath = "\\ServerPath\foo" 

function concatenateMetadata {
    $cFile = $metadataPath + "whiconcat.csv"
    Clear-Content $cFile
    $metadataFiles = gci $metadataPath
    $iterations = $metadataFiles.Count
    for ($i=0;$i -le $iterations-1;$i++) {
        $iFile = "whidata"+$i+".htm"
        $FileExists = (Test-Path $metadataPath$iFile -PathType Leaf)
        if (!($FileExists))
        {
            break
        }
        elseif ($FileExists)
        {
            Write-Host "Adding " $metadataPath$iFile
            Get-Content $metadataPath$iFile | Out-File $cFile -append
            Write-Host "to" $cfile
        }
    }
}
```

The `whidataXX.htm` files are encoded UTF8, but my output file is encoded UTF16. When I view the file in Notepad, it appears correct, but when I view it in a Hex Editor, the Hex value `00` appears between each character, and when I pull the file into a Java program for processing, the file prints to the console with extra spaces between `c h a r a c t e r s`.

First, is this normal for PowerShell? or is there something in the source files that would cause this?

Second, how would I fix this encoding problem in the code noted above?

Comment: In Powershell 6.0, this has been rendered unnecessary - Powershell now defaults to UTF-8 without encoding for redirection. See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4878

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Out-* cmdlets (like Out-File) format the data, and the default format is unicode.

You can add an -Encoding parameter to Out-file:

```
Get-Content $metadataPath$iFile | Out-File $cFile -Encoding UTF8 -append
```

or switch to Add-Content, which doesn't re-format

```
Get-Content $metadataPath$iFile | Add-Content $cFile
```

Comment: And to confirm, Add-Content will simply append the new data to the existing file, correct?

Comment: Yes.  It's counterpart Set-Content will overwrite the existing data.

Comment: In Powershell 6.0, this has been rendered unnecessary - Powershell now defaults to UTF-8 without encoding for redirection. See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4878

Answer (score 1):

First, the fact that you get 2 bytes per character indicates that fixed length UTF16  is being used. More accurately, it is called UCS-2. This article explains that file redirection in Powershell causes the output to be in UCS-2. See http://www.kongsli.net/nblog/2012/04/20/powershell-gotchas-redirect-to-file-encodes-in-unicode/. That same article also provides a fix.

Comment: Thanks for the article reference!