# Error message: Incomplete sql: ■p

Tags: sqlite

i have a corrupted Lightroom catalog file(.lrcat) which is a SQL database, which i usually repair by creating an SQL file using these commands:

```
echo .dump | sqlite3 CorruptedFile.lrcat > Temp.sql
```

From the SQL file i then rebuild the lrcat file with this command:

```
sqlite3 -init Temp.sql New.lrcat
```

In this case it loads the resources from the SQL file and after a while i get this message:

```
Error: incomplete SQL:  ■P
```

Since I am not a programmer, but a somewhat nerdy photographer I am stuck at this point. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Holger

Comment: Even if the database is corrupted, `.dump` should never generate invalid SQL. Can you upload the file somewhere?

Comment: Hi CL. Thanks for the quick response. I can upload it to Dropbox and send you the link, if you want to look at it.

Comment: I'm more interested in the .sql file. (Are you using the latest version of the `sqlite3` tool?)

Comment: I'm using sqlite 3.10.2. I have compressed the sql file and am uploading to Dropbox now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8b1ntqyf0yy3hf/Temp.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
000000: FF FE 50 00 52 00 41 00 47 00 4D 00 41 00 20 00  ..P.R.A.G.M.A. .
000010: 66 00 6F 00 72 00 65 00 69 00 67 00 6E 00 5F 00  f.o.r.e.i.g.n._.
000020: 6B 00 65 00 79 00 73 00 3D 00 4F 00 46 00 46 00  k.e.y.s.=.O.F.F.
000030: 3B 00 0D 00 0A 00 42 00 45 00 47 00 49 00 4E 00  ;.....B.E.G.I.N.
000040: 20 00 54 00 52 00 41 00 4E 00 53 00 41 00 43 00   .T.R.A.N.S.A.C.
000050: 54 00 49 00 4F 00 4E 00 3B 00 0D 00 0A 00 43 00  T.I.O.N.;.....C.
000060: 52 00 45 00 41 00 54 00 45 00 20 00 54 00 41 00  R.E.A.T.E. .T.A.
...
```

This is not a plain text file; it is encoded in UTF-16.
This might happen if you have modified the file in a misconfigured editor, or  [used PowerShell instead of `cmd.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388342/why-does-powershell-file-concatenation-convert-utf8-to-utf16).

Comment: You are absolutely right. Since there last update Windows 10 right clicking in the explorer brings up the Powershell and not CMD anymore. Now it all worked out nicely. Thanks a lot for your help. I need to find a good book and out learn SQL properly so I don't ask any more stupid questions. 