# GIT diff command working in powerShell with different options

Tags: git, powershell, github, git-commit

I am new to GIT commands and having tough time with it :(.
My requirement is to use GIT command in PowerShell and do some logic.
How to combine GIT diff with commitID and folder path?

**This works-**

```
>$(git diff --name-status HEAD~1..HEAD ROOT/subFolder)
```

output: `M   ROOT/subFolder/file.txt`            -----This is what I want but using commit id

**These commands don't work**

```
>$(git diff --name-status 5d658f9e ROOT/subFolder)       **with commit id**

>$(git diff --name-status 5d658f9e..HEAD -- ROOT/subFolder)  **with commit id & HEAD**

>$(git diff --name-status HEAD --diff-filter=ADMR -- ROOT/subFolder) **with commit id**
```

why the 1st command only works and others don't work?

Comment: What error message do you get when you try the bottom 3 commands?

Comment: Well, at least it is strange. It works (on my machine :)). Using latest Powershell Core, but tried it successfully in Windows Powershell 5.1.

`❯ $(git diff --name-status 10ca29..HEAD -- .\src\AzureLogging)`
`M       src/AzureLogging/Controllers/Worker.cs`

Comment: Be aware that PowerShell has a bad habit of messing with input and output streams, converting output to UTF-16-LE for instance. I avoid Windows so I am not up on all the details, but see, e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19388342/1256452). On the Git side, be aware that `git diff` is a *user oriented* command that obeys user configuration settings. For scripting purposes you should generally run `git diff-tree` or `git diff-index` or `git diff-files` or the like. Unfortunately the command line options for these are rather different than for `git diff`, and harder to get right.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

Now, for me the 2 commands **works** as expected:

> $(git diff --name-status 5d658f9e..HEAD -- ROOT/subFolder)  **with commit id & HEAD**

> $(git diff --name-status 5d658f9e..HEAD --diff-filter=ADMR -- ROOT/subFolder) **with commit id & HEAD**